# Retrieving element index in spfun, cellfun, arrayfun, etc. in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Is there any way to retrieve the **index** of the element on which a function called by `cellfun`, `arrayfun` or `spfun` acts? (i.e. retrieve the index of the element within the scope of the function).

For the sake of simplicity, imagine I have the following toy example:

```
S = spdiags([1:4]',0,4,4)
f = spfun(@(x) 2*x,S)
```

which builds a 4x4 sparse diagonal matrix and then multiplies each element by `2`.

And say that now, instead of multiplying each element by the constant number `2`, I would like to multiply it by **the index the element has in the original matrix**, i.e. assuming that `linear_index` holds the index for each element, it would be something like this:

```
S = spdiags([1:4]',0,4,4)
f = spfun(@(x) linear_index*x,S)
```

However, note the code above does not work (`linear_index` is undeclared).

This question is partially motivated by the fact that `blocproc` gives you access to `block_struct.location`, which one could argue references the location (~index) of *the current element* within the *full object* (an image in this case):

> `block_struct.location:` A two-element vector, [row col], that specifies
>   the position of the first pixel (minimum-row, minimum-column) of the
>   block data in the input image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, but you can supply the linear index as extra argument.

Both `cellfun` and `arrayfun` accept multiple input arrays. Thus, with e.g. arrayfun, you can write

```
a = [1 1 2 2];
lin_idx = 1:4;
out = arrayfun(@(x,y)x*y,a,lin_idx);
```

This doesn't work with `spfun`, unfortunately, since it only accepts a single input (the sparse array).

You can possibly use `arrayfun` instead, like so:

```
S = spdiags([1:4]',0,4,4);
lin_idx = find(S);

out = spones(S);
out(lin_idx) = arrayfun(@(x,y)x*y,full(S(lin_idx)),lin_idx);
%# or
out(lin_idx) = S(lin_idx) .* lin_idx;
```

Note that the call to `full` won't get you into memory trouble, since `S(lin_idx)` is 0% sparse.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a sparse matrix with linear_index filling instead of values.

Create `A`:

```
A(find(S))=find(S)
```

Then use `A` and `S` without spfun, e.g.: `A.*S`. This runs very fast.

Comment: The last line should be `A(sub2ind(i,j)) = find(S)`. Otherwise, you won't have the correct linear indices.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. Just make a cell like:
C = num2cell(1:length(S));
then:
out=arrayfun(@(x,c) c*x,S,C)