# Get index of current element of a 2-D matrix within arrayfun

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

Let `M` be some matrix:

```
M = rand(1000, 2000);
```

Consider the following code example:

```
A = zeros(size(M));
for row = 1:1000
    for col = 1:2000
        A(row, col) = M(row,col)*(row + col);
    end
end
```

How to compute the matrix `A` without `for` loops?

There is `arrayfun` function, but I don't know how get the index of the current element:

```
A = arrayfun(@(x)(x*(index(1) + index(2))), M); %// but how to get index???
```

Perhaps there are other solutions (and without extra loops)?

Comment: See also this question for a more general solution: [Retrieving element index in spfun, cellfun, arrayfun, etc. in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7741623/176071)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something simple like as follows to get a matrix that will represent `row+col` and then multiply that by M

```
M = rand(1000, 2000);
rowPlusCol = bsxfun(@plus,(1:size(M,1)).',1:size(M,2));
A = M.*rowPlusCol;
```

From my experience `bsxfun` is an extremely powerful function and can definitely save some run time, and this is a perfect example of that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative solution, boasting another fancy one-liner, for the sake of diversity:

```
A = M .* hankel(2:size(M, 1) + 1, size(M, 1) + 1:sum(size(M)));
```

Comment: +1 for introducing me to a new tool, the hankel matrix. I did not know this existed and that MATLAB had a nice implementation of it. It seems like it may be a bit of headache to implement and get correct first time, but definitely will do the trick

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible with `arrayfun`.

You can get row and column numbers using [meshgrid](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) and then do some simple matrix math.

```
M = rand(1000, 2000);
[cols,rows] = meshgrid(1:size(M,2), 1:size(M,1));
A = M .* (cols + rows);
```

Comment: Honestly, the `bsxfun` solution is much neater.

Comment: @EitanT thanks, I agree, not just because it is my answer but this solution will end up taking up much more space, especially if the size of `M` ever gets larger, you will need twice as much memory

Comment: @EitanT What do you mean by "neater"? I find it quite difficult to read and understand. I always prefer a simple, straightforward way of doing things unless performance is truly critical.

Comment: @shoelzer neater means shorter and faster. Yes, `bsxfun` is sometimes hard to read, but not in this case.